# Pass a transaction (or any other object) to a property?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have a property with a set and get method and it loads (in the get) and saves (in the set) data to/from ther DB. Now I want to have this in a transaction, which is a IDbTransaction in my case. The problem is, how could I give the property my transaction object? I already have the transaction in the code which uses the property...

Thanks :)

Comment: you save to DB in a setter? You are so going to coding hell! ;) Properties are supposed to be lightweight. Some of the worst coding errors I've ever seen were due to properties doing too much and having side effects

Comment: When you have a requirement to pass a parameter to your Property, it is usually a very good indication that the property should be a Method instead.

Comment: So I have a Set method and a Get Method which gets the transaction as param and does the DB stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current` ? It's a static property, documented  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the call to your property with a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object. Any call within the using block will be part of the transaction.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   // call properties and other code

   scope.Complete(); // needed or transaction rolls back
}
```